# Series of books; in one there is an island with very tall large pillars

Tags: story-identification

I forgot the name of these books, but they are for kids, and perhaps 200 pages apiece.

There is some magical element to them, but I forgot what exactly it was. I seem to remember conscience animals at one point, but all the characters are human.

I distinctly remember in one of the last books, there is an island with several large pillars of earth on it, and at least one or two of them are so high that they stretch into the clouds and are impossible to see or climb. Another is covered in grass at the top. The others have bridges across them, and the island is populated by people. The main characters come in a boat with knowledge of some big sea monster, and at the end of the book, the monster knocks over one of the tall pillars, and it does a domino effect. The final and tallest pillar crashes down on the monster and it is found to have spikes on it, like that was it's intended purpose.

I seem to remember the sea creature was released by a pair of boys accidentally from an underground lake in an earlier book. They were adults on the ship at the time that the group reaches the island.

I also distinctly remember a game of chess between a girl and a prison guard (or a prisoner maybe?) that the book showed move-by-move in an earlier book. In the same book, I remember some kind of underground tunnel used to escape from the city's walls where the girl lives.

Anyone know what series this is?

Comment: In the future could you please make the title a bit more meaningful and specific to the story-identification question you are asking?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you remember some other details like how long ago you read these books, color of book cover, name/age of characters etc? Anyone more can help

Comment: @Abhinav I remember there being maybe 7 books, and one doesn't have a book number (turns out it fit between 5 and 6 or something weird). I feel like most of the covers were blue. I read them probably 8 years ago, give or take. I think the characters were mostly kids age 12 or so and a couple adults. I don't remember any names. I think one cover might have a girl in a cave with glowing green symbols around her? Not quite sure, it's been a while.

Answer (score 4):

**I found it!** The name of the series is "The Land of Elyon." Thanks to Wikipedia's [complete list of fantasy novel series!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Fantasy_novel_series)

[image: Here is the cover of the book I remembered most]